# Black screen like GPay while recording?

Tags: android, google-pay, screen-recording

How to achieve black screen in our app while some one using screen recording, I seen this in **GPay** app while i tried payment transaction, that payment part is displayed as black screen in recorded video How to achieve in android app;

Answer (score 1):

in `onCreate()` method of activity (in which you want to disable recording/screenshot), add flag `FLAG_SECURE`. as (in kotlin):

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
```

this will prevent any screenshot or screen recording.